# I can't build docker image

Tags: 20.04, mount, docker, container

I try to build this simple dockerfile but its not working:

Dockerfil:

```
FROM nginx:latest
ADD . /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Command and output:

```
ife@ife-HP-ProBook-6560b:~$ docker build -t web:latest .
[+] Building 1.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.9s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                         0.3s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.7s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.2s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount370739963/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount370739963/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is common when a Dockerfile is not found.

The default name for it is `Dockerfile`, and it is case-sensitive. If your file is called `dockerfile`, for example, make sure you capitalize the `D` in the filename.

Otherwise, you can pass the `--file` argument and overwrite the default name.

```
docker build -t web:latest --file custom-dockerfile .
```